# matplotlib yaxis level overlapping

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have following line of code for the yaxis

```
ax.yaxis.set_tick_params(which='minor',
                         direction='out', 
                         length=1,
                         labelsize=8,
                         labelleft='off',
                         labelright='on',
                        )
```

This one ok, because i reduced the font size

[image]

the below one is not even readable 
[image]

how to add a parameter so that, it will not overlap when the values are so close

Comment: I do not believe what you want is possible in MPL.

Comment: There is no parameter that would prevent axis labels from overlapping.

Comment: Is there any other trick in matplot lib that will allow this?

Comment: This library for moving plot labels might help. Not sure if it works well for labels outside the drawing box though. https://github.com/Phlya/adjustText/blob/master/docs/source/Examples.ipynb